# Selecting the default rule

Tags: c#, dsl, rule-engine

I'm trying to find the name of what I want to achieve. We need to build a rules engine with some fallback or fail over logic.

[image: DSL]

When the request is JP, the first rule should be selected; for any other country, it should pick up the second one. I don't want to put an entry for all the countries we'll be dealing with, hence the '*'.

What is this called? How is this built in C#?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

My guess that you are looking for a flavor of rule engine implementation for C#

One solution would be to use [NRules](https://github.com/NRules/NRules/wiki/Getting-Started) library.

You can easily create any rule you want

```
public class DiscountNotificationRule : Rule
{
    public override void Define()
    {
        Customer customer = null;

        When()
            .Match<Customer>(() => customer)
            .Exists<Order>(o => o.Customer == customer, o => o.PercentDiscount > 0.0);

        Then()
            .Do(_ => customer.NotifyAboutDiscount());
    }
}
```

Extra information in the getting started page of the library.